# How get the good syntax for multiple foreign key with sqlite in android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, foreign-keys, android-sqlite

I am trying to put 2 foreign keys in sqlite with android studio but I get the error below :

Multiple Foreign Key Error

[image]
Whereas it works for me when I get only 1 foreign key as you can see below :

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + RENDEZ_VOUS_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + DATE + " DATE, "
            + TIME + " TIME, "
            + STATUS + " INTEGER, "
            + COMMENT + " TEXT, "
            + CONTACT_ID + " INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY("+CONTACT_ID+") REFERENCES "+DatabaseManagerContact.TABLE_NAME+"("+CONTACT_ID+"));";

    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    Log.i("DATABASE Rendez Vous", "onCreate invoked ");
}
```

Do you have an idea from where is the problem??

Regards

Comment: I already read those link but it did not answered to my question because this is not a multiple foreign key problem. As I said in my post, my foreign works well alone but not when I set 2 of them.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare all the Foreign keys at the end of the statement, like this:

```
String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
        + RENDEZ_VOUS_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + DATE + " DATE, "
        + TIME + " TIME, "
        + STATUS + " INTEGER, "
        + COMMENT + " TEXT, "
        + CONTACT_ID + " INTEGER, "
        + OTHER_ID +  " INTEGER, "
        + FOREIGN KEY("+CONTACT_ID+") REFERENCES "+DatabaseManagerContact.TABLE_NAME+"("+CONTACT_ID+"), "
        + FOREIGN KEY("+OTHER_ID+") REFERENCES "+DatabaseManagerContact.ANOTHER_TABLE_NAME+"("+ANOTHER_ID+"));";
```

Comment: Hi, 

It works well !  thanks a lot.

Comment: I am trying but i do not find where i can accept your answer.